# ITRF2008 to WGS84 Datum Transformation in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcgis-10.2, wgs84

If I have data in IRTF2008 as shapefile is it possible to change this to WGS84 and how?

The need for this comes when trying to display the data in a third party program that doesn't recognize the .prj for the IRTF 2008 data.

I'm Using ArcGIS 10.2.2 and can't seem to find a transformation for this application.

Comment: What accuracy do you need?

Comment: Ideally 1m, but whatever I can get might be exceptable.

Comment: If you only need 1 m, redefine the data's coordinate reference system as WGS84. WGS84 is now kept aligned with ITRF at the 10 cm level. BUT, this [document](ftp://itrf.ensg.ign.fr/pub/itrf/WGS84.TXT) states that ITRF2008 and G1674 "are likely to agree at the cm level." It also states that there is no tfm available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redefining the original file as WGS84 does the trick at least for accuracy for any practical purpose.  The following was sent by a customer care rep at ESRI...

1]  ITRF 2008 is a datum definition that takes continental drift into consideration.

2]  The WGS 1984 definition used in ArcGIS Desktop is the original definition, and has not been updated to take any plate tectonic motion into account.

3]  There is no geographic transformation available between the original definition for WGS 1984 and ITRF 2008.  The transformations that exist between WGS 1984 and ITRF, or even between different epochs in ITRF, have 0 parameters, which means that they are being treated as being identical.